# 可変長のコマンドラインオプションから、リストデータと辞書データに変換して取得したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonが起動されたときのコマンドラインオプションをパースし、
コマンドライン引数を、リストデータと、辞書データとして取得することはできないでしょうか？

実行するコマンドライン

```
python3 test.py aa bb --key1 10 --key2 20
```

Pythonで取得したいデータ

```
arg_list = ['aa', 'bb']
arg_map = { 'key1':'10', 'key2':'20' }
```

argparseを利用すればできそうなのですが、
可変長のリストデータと、辞書データとして分割して取得することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 単純なリスト用のオプション指定(--list等)を作ったり、オプション指定をキーにするのではなく、辞書用のオプション(--dict等)と`キー=値`とか`キー:値`と言う風に指定方法を工夫してみてはどうでしょう？ [\[Python\] ArgumentParser でコマンドライン引数を解析する](https://webbibouroku.com/Blog/Article/python-argparse), [Pythonでリスト型のコマンドライン引数を受け取る](https://qiita.com/hook125/items/0ffc6b9391ccb0abcd52), [python-argparseで辞書型のオプションを与える](https://qiita.com/Hi-king/items/de960b6878d6280eaffc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントで示したように、`aa bb`のパラメータについても指定するためのオプションを追加したり、辞書は1個1個をオプションとするのではなく辞書型パラメータのオプションとして定義すれば出来ます。
可変長(というか可変個数)とするには、[add_argument()](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument) の [nargs](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) パラメータに`'+'`(1個以上)または`'*'`(0個でも可)を指定すれば良いでしょう。

こちらの記事を参考に：
[[Python] ArgumentParser でコマンドライン引数を解析する](https://webbibouroku.com/Blog/Article/python-argparse)
[Pythonでリスト型のコマンドライン引数を受け取る](https://qiita.com/hook125/items/0ffc6b9391ccb0abcd52)
[python-argparseで辞書型のオプションを与える](https://qiita.com/Hi-king/items/de960b6878d6280eaffc)
[How can I pass a list as a command-line argument with argparse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15753701/9014308)

上記記事やPythonの仕様説明を混ぜてこんな風に出来るでしょう。

```
import argparse

class DictArgs(argparse.Action):
    """
    --dict foo=a型の引数を辞書に入れるargparse.Action
    """
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_strings=None):
        arg_dict = getattr(namespace,self.dest,[])
        if arg_dict is None:
            arg_dict = {}

        for x in values:
            k, v = x.split("=")
            arg_dict[k] = v

        setattr(namespace, self.dest, arg_dict)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='an example program')

parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', required=False, nargs='*', help='list of string variables') 
parser.add_argument('-d', '--dict', required=False, nargs='*', action=DictArgs, help='dictionary variables')

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.list)
print(args.dict)
```

(Windowsでは)こんな風にコマンドラインで指定して実行すれば：

```
py argsample.py --list aa bb --dict key1=10 key2=20
```

printの結果はこんな風に表示されます。

```
['aa', 'bb']
{'key1': '10', 'key2': '20'}
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。期待しいたとおりの結果が得られました。--list、--dictで指定することで分かりやすくなったとも思います。